# Example of 2nd-countable T2 quotient of topological manifold that is not a topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

What is an example of a *topological* manifold (i.e., second-countable, locally Euclidean $T_2$-space) $M$ and a quotient space $M/\sim$ of $M$ that is *not* again a topological manifold even though it is second-countable and $T_2$?

An example with $M$ compact would be especially welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need for the purpose of cooking up an example is a compact topological manifold $M$, a Hausdorff space $X$, and a continuous surjective function $f : M \to X$. The universal properties of quotient maps then produce an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $M$ such that $M/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $X$: the equivalence relation is simply $x \sim y \iff f(x)=f(y)$; and the homeomorphism from $M / \sim$ to $X$ is induced by $f$.

Simple examples abound.

For instance, take $M=S^1$ to be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$, a compact 1-manifold. Let $X$ be the cross
$$X = \bigl([-1,+1] \times \{0\}\bigr) \cup \bigl(\{0\} \times [-1,+1] \bigr)
$$
Define the surjective continuous function $f : S^1 \to X$ in a piecewise fashion: subdivide $S^1$ into octants; map each octant homeomorphically into the closest branch of the cross. For example, on the octant $0 \le \theta \le \pi/4$ define
$$f(e^{2\pi i \theta}) = \bigl(1 - \frac{4}{\pi} \theta, 0 \bigr)
$$
and on the octant $-\pi/4 \le \theta \le 0$ define
$$f(e^{2\pi i \theta}) = \bigl(1 + \frac{4}{\pi} \theta, 0 \bigr)
$$
As one can from these formulas, one portion of the equivalence relation is
$$\theta \sim -\theta \quad\text{if $-\pi/4 \le \theta \le \pi/4$}
$$
The other three portions are
\begin{align*}
\theta \sim \pi-\theta &\quad\text{if $\pi/4 \le \theta \le 3 \pi/4$} \\
\theta \sim 2\pi - \theta &\quad\text{if $3\pi/4 \le \theta \le 5 \pi/4$} \\
\theta \sim 3 \pi - \theta &\quad\text{if $5\pi/4 \le \theta \le 7 \pi/4$} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice -- even better than the vertical projection of $S^2$ onto the closed interval $[-1, 1]$ -- in that the quotient space here is not even a manifold-with-boundary. But still just one singular point preventig that. I wonder if there's stil a better example, one less like a manfold-with-boundary.

Comment: That's the thing about quotient maps, they are indeed very easy to construct. In fact there is a quotient map from $S^2$ onto the [Menger curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge).

Answer (score 0):

For something that's not a manifold with boundary, and looks a bit pathological, consider any strange-enough looking [Peano continuum](https://wildtopology.com/category/general-topology/peano-continuum/). For any such continuum $X$ there exists a continuous surjection from $[0, 1]$ to $X$, hence, composing the projection from $S^1$ to $[-1, 1]$ with homeomorphism $[-1, 1]\cong [0, 1]$ and then surjection $[0, 1]\to X$, we obtain that any Peano continuum is a quotient map of the circle $S^1$.

For example, the Wazewski's universal dendrite: [image]

Comment: That works. Of course the quotient is a manifold-with-boundary.